# GEOIP for IIS 10

Tags: iis, windows-server-2016, geoip

I'm migrating from Apache 2.4 back to IIS 10. IIS does have a IP restriction interface but there is noway to GEO ban by country. 
Is there a similar module than Apache Maxmind Geo IP module for IIS? Also, what is the workflow (if any) to remotely add (by code) an entry to that IP list in the IP restriction interface?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use **ModSecurity**, *an open source, cross-platform web application firewall (WAF) module*, as it has support for IIS. Download [ModSecurity for IIS MSI Installer](http://www.modsecurity.org/download.html) and follow [Installation information for IIS](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual#Installation_for_Microsoft_IIS) for prerequisites and installation instructions.

When you have installed ModSecurity and configured it for your site, things works similarly in IIS, Apache and Nginx.

ModSecurity uses ModSecurity Rule Language for describing how to operate with HTTP transaction data. There are many things you could do with *the "Swiss Army Knife" of WAFs*, but you can use the [GEO collection](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual#geo) for

- blocking a country, lets say North Korea

  ```
  SecGeoLookupDb /usr/local/geo/data/GeoLiteCity.dat
  SecRule REMOTE_ADDR "@geoLookup" "chain,id:20,drop,msg:'Block North Korea IP address'"
  SecRule GEO:COUNTRY_CODE "@streq KP"
  ```
- blocking anything outside the United Kingdom

  ```
  SecGeoLookupDb /usr/local/geo/data/GeoLiteCity.dat
  SecRule REMOTE_ADDR "@geoLookup" "chain,id:22,drop,msg:'Non-GB IP address'"
  SecRule GEO:COUNTRY_CODE "!@streq GB"
  ```
- for the rest you have already figured out the pattern and also able to read the Reference Manual.